# Error 91 in assigning the value of a cell to a variable

Tags: vba, variables

I want to assign the variable "searched word" the value of cell J6. This cell is of type Stream.
When I run the code I get error 91. How can I fix it?

```
Sub Search ()
Dim word search As Stream
Worksheets ("Actual"). Cells (6, 10) .Select
searchword = Sheets ("Actual"). Range ("J6"). Value
```

> Error 91: Object variable or With block not set

Comment: Your declaration is incorrect. `Dim wordsearch As Stream`. You then use `searchword` as your variable in your assignment statement...

Comment: BTW you could omit `Worksheets ("Actual"). Cells (6, 10) .Select`. You hardly want to `Select` anything